# Grep Pattern Repetition

Tags: unix, grep

I have a csv (comma separated file). I would like to know how to search for a pattern where the 7th and 8th field are the same using only grep (no using `cut`). I have tried something like this:

```
grep -E '[^,]*,{6,6}' input.csv | grep '\(.*\)\(,\)\(\1$\)' | less
```

Unfortunately, this does not print anything. How could I get the output I need?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming there's nothing awkward like fields with commas in them (because if there are such fields in the first 8 fields, you can't process the files without a full CSV-cognizant tool), and that there is a 9th field (so the 7th and 8th fields are both followed by a comma) then:

```
grep '^\([^,]*,\)\{6\}\([^,]*,\)\2' file.csv
```

The first bit says 6 sequences of zero-or-more non-commas, each followed by a comma.  Then there's the 7th (possibly empty) field with its trailing comma; that's followed by the same-thing-again (the `\2`).

```
$ cat file.csv
a,b,c,d,e,f,g,g,i
a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i
a,b,c,d,e,f,hhh,hhh,i
,b,c,d,e,f,hhh,hhh,i
,,c,d,e,f,hhh,hhh,i
,,,d,e,f,hhh,hhh,i
,,,,e,f,hhh,hhh,i
,,,,,f,hhh,hhh,i
,,,,,,hhh,hhh,i
,,,,,,hhh,hhh,
$ grep '^\([^,]*,\)\{6\}\([^,]*,\)\2' file.csv
a,b,c,d,e,f,g,g,i
a,b,c,d,e,f,hhh,hhh,i
,b,c,d,e,f,hhh,hhh,i
,,c,d,e,f,hhh,hhh,i
,,,d,e,f,hhh,hhh,i
,,,,e,f,hhh,hhh,i
,,,,,f,hhh,hhh,i
,,,,,,hhh,hhh,i
,,,,,,hhh,hhh,
$
```

Note that the `g,h,i` line does not appear in the output (and it shouldn't); the rest should and do appear.

All of this is done using POSIX [Basic Regular Expressions](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html) or BREs.  If you use `egrep` or `grep -E`, you have Extended Regular Expressions or EREs at your disposal and you can forego all the backslashes except the `\2`; you could also deal with a file that has some lines with 8 fields and other lines with 9 or more, but that isn't a regular CSV file.  The BRE version can also be modified to work with a CSV file that has precisely 8 columns:

```
grep '^\([^,]*,\)\{6\}\([^,]*\),\2$' file.csv
```

Part of the art of using regular expressions is having a flexible mindset about different ways to achieve a given result; there is often more than one way to do it.

Comment: +1 Good answer. But this would be sooo much easier with `awk`: `awk -F, '$7==$8' file.txt`

Comment: Works like a charm. Will go through it and understand. Thanx

Comment: @steve: Agreed, but the question stipulated 'no `cut`' and 'only `grep`' so I rather assumed that `awk` (and Perl and ...) were not allowed either.

Answer (score 1):

if at all you are interested in awk ,it would be more simple:

```
awk -F, '$7==$8' your_file
```

or in perl:

```
perl -F, -ane 'if($F[6]==$F[7]){print}' your_file
```

Comment: Thanx...awk is going to be my next topic.